# Mixing ngx-leaflet with nav menu (visual studio web default) for angular

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I'm trying to combine a nav-menu with leaflet. The problem is that the map won't load unless it's in app.component.html, and I don't know why. I want to have the map load on a new tab, in a component that isn't the main one.

Steps taken: Make a copy of the example here:
https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-ngcli
Added the nav menu and routing from the visual studio template, put the leaflet example code in there.

Here is a reduced version of the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-lpketz?file=angular.json

As you can see, the default page has a loaded map, but if you switch to the leaflet tab it will not work.